# retrieving instagram stories data using instagram api

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I want to access and retrieve a user's Stories post from Instagram using their Dev API.

I tested after posting a story myself by using `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`.

However, that returns an empty object unless I post a regular post.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware the Instagram API does not currently return Stories.

The example response in the documentation for the media endpoint, for example, shows responses for Images, Videos and Carousel items only.  The recent media end point documentation doesn't go into much detail on responses.

[Media End Point Documentation](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/#get_media)

Comment: curious why they have not added this to APi yet

Comment: I suspect they are trying to keep it a feature that forces people to interact with the Instagram app/site.  The Carousel posts feature was introduced after the Stories so I'm not expecting them to be made available on the API anytime soon sadly.

Answer (score 1):

It is available only for Instagram Business Account.

See this link for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/stories/

The id returned by this endpoint can be used on the same API media endpoint.

Comment: I want to display user story after login than how it is works?